# MPI Isend and Irecv problems

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I'm having trouble with my MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv blocks of code. I need to send a number Cin to the next process up the line, then the current process can go about it's business.

The receiving process needs to receive before it can go further in it's calculations, but when I don't have MPI_Wait it nevers gets the data, and when I do it just hangs forever. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I only set Cin to 3 in order to see when the message doesn't go through. Currently it just hangs.

```
void ComputeS5C()
{
    MPI_Request send_request, recv_request;
    MPI_Status status;
    int Cin[1] = {3};
    if(my_rank == 0){Cin[0] = 0;}
    else {
        MPI_Irecv(Cin, 1, MPI_INT, my_rank - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_request);
        MPI_Wait(&recv_request, &status);
        fprintf(stderr, "RANK:%d   Message Received from rank%d: Cin=%d\n", my_rank, my_rank-1, Cin[0]);
    }

    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < Size_5; k++)
    {
        int s5clast;
        if(k==0)
        {
            s5clast = Cin[0];
        }
        else
        {
            s5clast = s5c[k-1];
        }

        s5c[k] = s5g[k] | (s5p[k]&s5clast);
    }

    //if not highest rank, pass the carryin upstream
    if(my_rank < world_size - 1){
        MPI_Isend(&s5c[k], 1, MPI_INT, my_rank+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request);
        fprintf(stderr, "RANK:%d   Message sent to rank%d: Cin=%d\n", my_rank, my_rank+1, s5c[k]);
    }
    MPI_Wait(&send_request, &status);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error in your code has to do with the missmatch of `tags`. Messages are sent using a `tag = 1` and received using `tag = 0`. Sends and receives are not matching explaining why all processes are stuck waiting that sent messages get consumed. Change the tags so that they match.

A note, when using `MPI_Irecv` you always need an `MPI_Wait` to be sure to know when it is safe to consume received data. I think in your example use of `MPI_Recv` is more approriate.

Comment: Good catch! Here I was thinking tags didn't really matter.

Comment: tags are very important my friend ...expecially when you need 15 points in stackoverflow :)

Comment: I'd like to chime in and add that without the `MPI_Wait` for each and every request (send or recv), you code will probably still run but the message completion timings will blow up to the order of tens of seconds and only might throw an error.   Keep this in mind when debugging!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you communicate one rank after the other sequentially. Quite large overhead.